How can we migrate from TFVC to GIT, without halting development?
At our company we have a very old codebase which is hosted using TFVC on Azure DevOps. The repository has grown to be +- 10GB, which would be way too big for a GIT repository. It contains a lot of redundant data which we'd be able to prune away. However, this will take some time and we don't want to halt development during this migration process.
The old repo is roughly set up like this:
$Project  
|\_FolderA  
|\_FolderB  
|\_FolderC  
|\_FolderC_OLD  
|\_SomeAssetsFolder  
|\_Some3rdParyLibraryFolder*

The folders aren't branches. They are folders inside of the root of the project.
Our strategy to move to GIT was as following;

Branch the project to a new project
Prune the new project while development continues on the old projectrepo
Once pruning and other necessary edits are done, merge the old projectRepo into the new project
Convert the new repo to a GIT repo using Git-TFS
Done

However, this doesn't seem to work as intended; we can't seem to branch the whole project, only folders inside of the project.

Will we be able to merge the old project into the new one, even if we have to branch each folder individually?
Is there another way to clone the complete project into a new project, allowing us to merge the changes at a later moment?


Is 10GB the size of the entire repository? Or the size of the checked out files?

Could you branch, prune, and merge one folder at a time?

Your plan of "clean up the repo, then convert" would be a good one if it could be made to work.

we can't seem to branch the whole project, only folders inside of the project.

Could you branch, prune, and merge one folder at a time?


The repository has grown to be +- 10GB, which would be way too big for a GIT repository.

(Assuming this is the size of the checked out files, not the size of the repository. If it's the size of the repository, Git might be able to do better.)
It's not too big, it just makes cloning slow.

My general approach would be...

Do the conversion to Git and cleanup.
Continue working in TFVC until that's done.
Stop work on TFVC.
Update your Git repo with git-tfs pull.
Continue work in Git.

Note: I don't know much about TFS or TFVC, but this is a strategy I've used converting in the past.
More specifically...

Write a .gitignore file to ignore outdated large files.
Migrate your repo using git-tfs.
Use git-lfs to store your remaining large assets reducing repository size.
Verify the conversion.
Stop work on TFVC.

Everybody saves their uncommitted work as patch files.
Set TFVC read-only, if possible.


Update your Git repo with the latest changes using git-tfs pull.
Start work on Git.

Everybody applies their patches.



